# Javascript - Passed by Reference and called function twice

Tags: javascript, pass-by-reference

The first time I called the function, it worked correctly: it returned "now60."
I used document.write immediately after it, to see if I correctly passed by reference: it returned 60, instead of the initial value of 30 - thus, I did.

The second time I called the function, the function did nothing. It did not print now120, or even error. Also, document.write displayed 60, again.

```
var quickChallengeTimer = {timer:30}; var quickChallengeQuestion; 
var quickChallengeAnswer; var quickChallengeResponse;

    function quickChallenge(quickChallengeTimerfunc, quickChallengeQuestion, quickChallengeAnswer) {

        if (typeof quickChallengeResponse == 'undefined') {
            switch (quickChallengeTimerfunc.timer) {

                case 30:
                    quickChallengeTimerfunc.timer = 60;
                    quickChallengeResponse = 'undefined';
                    document.write("now60");
                    break;

                case 60:
                    quickChallengeTimerfunc.timer = 120;
                    quickChallengeResponse = 'undefined';
                    document.write("now120");
                    break;

                default:
                    document.write("Error");
                    break;
            }
        }

        console.dir(quickChallengeTimerfunc.timer);
    }



quickChallenge(quickChallengeTimer);
document.write("<br />" + quickChallengeTimer.timer);

quickChallenge(quickChallengeTimer);
document.write("<br />" + quickChallengeTimer.timer);
```

Comment: What are you expecting from that code above?

Comment: `document.write()` is something that you basically should never ever user, under almost any circumstances, unless you *really* know what it does.

Comment: james emanon, I'm expect it to print now120 and change the value of quickChallengeTimer.timer to 120, the second time I call the function. The first time works correctly, it changes 30 to 60. The second time, 60 remains 60.

Comment: Pointy, I'm just looking for an equivalent to var_dump. Console.dir isn't working very well. I can't get firefox to show any useful data, and Chrome only sometimes does. Can you suggest an alternative?

Comment: Why not console.log?

Comment: james emanon, I had the same result with that: No useful data in firefox or firebug. :(